# Conditional columns from multiple string values in multiple column

Tags: python, gis, arcmap

I would like to make a conditional column based on the string values in 3 other columns in arcmap (field calculator). Lets say

1. Column_1 = a, b, c, d
2. Column_2 = x, y, z, j, 1, 2
3. Column_3 =  m, n, 0, 1,

then the return I expect in the new column is as follows:

```
'I' if [Column_1 is 'a' or 'b'] and [Column_2 is 'j' or '1' or '2'] and [Column_3 is 'm' or 'n'] 

'II' if [Column_1 is 'a' or 'b'] and [Column_2 is 'y' or 'z' or 'j'] and [Column_3 is '0' or '1']
```

Each other combination would return `'III'`.

My code is :

```py
def fnX('Column_1', 'Column_2', 'Column_3'):

  if (Column_1 == 'a' or 'b') and (Column_2 == 'j' or '1' or '2') and (Column_3 == 'm' or 'n'):
    return 'I'

  elif (Column_1 == 'a' or 'b') and (Column_2 == 'y' or 'z' or 'j') and (Column_3 == '0' or '1'):
    return 'II'

  else:
    return 'III'
```

I tried the code above but it didn't succeed. All returns are `'I'`. Is there any other mechanic that can be used to replace `if`-`elif`-`else`?

Comment: The first column has values fewer than the second one, is this data for a dataframe or only lists?

Comment: `or` doesn't work as you expect. For example: `Column_1 == 'a' or 'b')` should be `Column_1 == 'a' or Column_1 == 'b')` or `Column_1 in {'a', 'b'}`.

Answer (score 2):

- When you want to compare all values of list with a scalar value, you cannot compare the entire list to the scalar directly `Column_1 == 'a'`, you should have a loop to iterate throught each element of the list or convert a list to a numpy array np.array(Column_1 ).
- When you have multiple conditions in your comparison you should repeat the same comparison with the other conditions: `Column_1[0] == 'a' or Column_1[0] == 'b'` instead of `Column_1[0] == 'a' or 'b'`.
- You cannot iterate through the three lists together at the same time because Column_2 has 5 elements while other lists have only 4 elements.

I will assume that Column_2 has only the first 4 values:

```
Column_1 = ['a','a','a','a']
Column_2 = ['x','y','z','1']
Column_3 = ['m','n','0','1']

for i,j,k in zip(Column_1,Column_2,Column_3):
    if i in {'a','b'} and j in {'j','1','2'} and k in {'m','n'}:
        print('I')
    elif i in {'a','b'} and j in {'y','z','j'} and k in {'0','1'}:
        print('II')
    else:
        print('III')

#OUTPUT
III
III
II
III
```

Comment: You could use itertools.zip_longest for columns of different length (not sure if it matters, though)

Answer (score 0):

I quickly rewrote your code into this based on the comments. Give it a try.

```
def fnX(Column_1, Column_2, Column_3):

  if (Column_1 in {'a','b'} and (Column_2 in {'j', '1','2'} and (Column_3 == {'m', 'n'}): 
    return 'I'

  elif (Column_1 in {'a', 'b'} and (Column_2 in {'y', 'z', 'j'}) and (Column_3 in {'0', '1'}): 
    return 'II'

  else: 
    return 'III'
```

Comment: Column_1 in {'a','b'}  is invalid condition! Column_1  is  a list not scalar value.

Comment: Oh. I think the other answer should work. Give that a try too!